# Android JIT compiler: when are methods compiled/optimized

Tags: android, performance, dalvik

From my knowledge the Java JIT compiler traces called methods and after a certain amount of method/loop executions compiles the code or optimizes it based on the executed code paths so far. The number of method executions is something like 10000 (depends on JVM and settings) with some aging.

I am wondering when the Android JIT compiler actually kicks in (number of method invocations and other metrics). The reason is that I logged the used CPU time for a code part with android.os.Process.getElapsedCpuTime() and now wonder when I should expect to see some improvements (if any at all).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some insight if you haven't watched it already: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/jit-compiler-androids-dalvik-vm.html